# Experiment of liquid filled rod doing oscillation is called?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, momentum

I know this is a weird question but I can't find any reference to this experiment, I have Google a lot and now I need the experts help.

There is a physics experiment where a liquid filled rod is balanced on a triangular object at its centre of gravity and the rod keeps on doing motion cause of momentum (I think).

Can you please help me recall the experiment and the concept involved.

Comment: What type of motion is it doing?  Could you add a diagram?

Comment: Are you thinking of this? [Drinking bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird)